# preg_replace - Only match when surrounded by spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here's my existing code:

```
preg_replace("!((([a-z]{3,5}://))". "[-a-z0-9.]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}". "(:[0-9]+)?". "(/([^\s]*[^\s,.])?)?". "(\?([^\s]*[^\s,.])?)?)!i",  "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>", $s);
```

It takes a link and turns it into HTML.

The problem is that sometimes I get a URL that I don't want to turn into HTML.  For example:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/img.png" />
```

so that would turn into:

```
<img src="<a target="_blank" href ...
```

What is the best way to prevent this?  I think only taking links between a space might work well.  How would I alter the preg_replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`).

```
preg_replace("!\b((([a-z]{3,5}://))". "[-a-z0-9.]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}". "(:[0-9]+)?". "(/([^\s]*[^\s,.])?)?". "(\?([^\s]*[^\s,.])?)?)\b!i",  "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>", $s);
```

Though my preferred technique would be to search in text nodes only so you don't ever have to deal with serialised HTML.

If you decide to parse the HTML, [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is quite handy.